# Trouble in river city with CSS

Tags: css, overflow, background-color

Ok here is the site:

http://danberinger.com/

If you view the source for the HTML and CSS you can see that I have set the height of the div in the middle to 100% and given it an overflow property value of hidden, it is called "main_content".  I realized that the height value is having no effect on what is displayed, the overflow value of hidden is allowing the background color of the main_content div to extend down to the footer.  I guess I am wondering what the best way for me to achieve a variable div height on each page or "main_content" while maintaining the background color.  Am I doing this the right way or am I using some kind of css hack that is not the proper way to do it.  All insight is welcome.  Make sure to take a look at the source HTML and CSS before giving me an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to assign the background color to your `body` element. Something like this:

```
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

This will also eliminate the few pixel white border around the edges, if you want to maintain that, take out the `margin` and `padding` declarations.

Comment: Ok, but then if I do that then that gray color will also fill any unused space in the browser window below the footer, I guess that just goes with the territory, I will have to set the padding to like 100px on the top and bottom of that message box?

Comment: @Dan - Something like this may be a better solution: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page It's a good tutorial on getting your footer to stay at the bottom of the page.  I prefer that the footer stays down there, but up to you if you want padding or fixing it to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood what you want, but try this:

Replace div#intro_container with:

```
div#intro_container {
width:830px;
margin:auto;
overflow: hidden;
background-color:#333333;
}
```

And remove the height property from div#messagebox.

Comment: It looks like this for me, is this want you want?

http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/3203/danb.png

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do in this way:

In the content of div 'main-content', add

In your case it was

```
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="navigation">..</div>
    <div id="intro_container">..</div>
</div>
```

It cam be rewritten as

```
<div id="main_content">
    <div id="navigation">..</div>
    <div id="intro_container">..</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

AFAIK This is a standard way to achieve what are you doing.